# Laravel API closing connection before getting any response

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I have a small Laravel application. I developed an API and using postman to get data. But somehow the laravel server seems to be closing connection and reopening on a different port whenever I make an api request.

The log is as follows:

```
C:\Projects\PHP\security>php artisan serve
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
127.0.0.1:64875 Accepted
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8001
PHP 8.0.1 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8001) started
```

My routes/api.php is defined as follows:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'user']);
});
```

The controller function is:

```
 public function user()
    {
        return new UserResource(Auth::user());
    }
```

Laravel cors is as follows:

```
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

I have tried uninstalling Antivirus, rebooting the server, rebooting computer to avail. The web side of things seems intact though. I can login and do whatver ever I want. The only problem comes when testing the API

Where could I be going wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how you are trying to fetch from postman??? are you using the /api/users url?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to start Laravel with other HTTP Server as Apache? Most of the time the process reset itself and strat on other port. This doesn't happen with HTTP Server